# Info Palette went missing. How can I get it back?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My Info Palette disappeared in Illustrator. Is there a keyboard command to get it back? I have looked in the help files, I have looked in the Windows and Views menus but cannot find anything. It is the ribbon of info at the top (gives details on any element selected in the illustrator design), just under the menu items.

Thanks for any help!
Wendy

Comment: Uh if you've looked at all of these things then I suspect you're using the wrong terminology which would make it hard for us to help you. The Info Panel can be easily accessed from the Window menu and would be in the help file. Could you maybe find a screenshot of Illustrator, circle the part you can't access, and then [edit] your post to include it?

Comment: Uh, good idea. I'll edit my post as soon as I have access to that computer again.

Answer (score 2):

it's actually not info if I understand you right - it's Control. It has no shortcut, go to Window>control and it should work for you. Otherwise reset the workspace.

Comment: Oh, YES!!! Thank you! I did search for all the names and functions of the menus, but could not find a definition for that menu anywhere!! I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.